# flask_login, How to get current_user from a new thread?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I'm new to flask_login library. In my codebase, after user login, I can get the current user information from `current_user` of `flask_login` library. The simplified test code is below:

```
from threading import Thread
from flask_login import current_user

def test():
    print("current_user = ", current_user)   # None
worker = Thread(target=test)
worker.start()
print("current_user = ", current_user)       #  <XXX.auth.view.User object at 0x119b2b250>
```

So I'm very confusing why I can't get the current user information from a separate thread, even after I deliberately import again before the first `print` statement.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_user` is a thread-local value - it will behave as a separate variable in every thread. You must pass it between threads if you need it elsewhere.

Perhaps your call would become:

```py
from threading import Thread
from flask_login import current_user

user = current_user

def test(user):
    print("current_user = ", user)

worker = Thread(target=test, args=(user,))
worker.start()

print("current_user = ", user)
```

---

Relevant line from the `flask_login` source:

```py
current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
```

https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-login/blob/d22f80d166ee260d44e0d2d9ea973b784ef3621b/flask_login/utils.py#L26

---

Relevant discussion of werkzeug's implementations of locals from the werkzeug docs:

> Werkzeug provides its own implementation of local data storage called
>   werkzeug.local. This approach provides a similar functionality to
>   thread locals but also works with greenlets.

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/local/#werkzeug.local.LocalProxy

Comment: How can I resolve this problem if I want to get current user from `from flask_login import current_user`，is there any way?

Comment: I added a potential solution - not tested though - let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: The reason why I want to get the current user in a new thread through `from flask_login import current_user` is that I have very deep nested code，if I pass `user` to the nested code, that would be very ugly.

Comment: That's tough - deeply nested code is usually something to avoid for reasons like yours (Zen of Python line 5). Might be worth a refactor to get back to a flat structure.